# Remove Apps Button From Favorites Tray In 5.1.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I'm running 5.1.1 on a rooted LG Tribute LS675ZV5. I would like to remove the apps button from the favorites tray. This version of Android doesn't have that setting in the homescreen settings. I've googled(DuckDuckGoed actually) high and low and can find no solution.

Although I did discover Xposed and it seems you can do anything you want to Android with that. Perhaps including this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give another chance to Izzy's list on [Home Replacements (Launchers/Homescreens)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher) and ended up using [Smart Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ginlemon.flowerfree). It works great.